# Express: app.use() adding middeware as multiple args versus separate statements?

Tags: node.js, express

Let's say I have an express web app for which I'm adding some of the standard middleware:

```
app.use(express.static(config.staticRoot, { maxAge: 300000 }));
app.use(compression());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

What's the difference between the above and if I had called it like this:

```
app.use(
  express.static(config.staticRoot, { maxAge: 300000 }),
  compression(),
  cookieParser(),
  bodyParser.json(),
  bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }),
  passport.initialize(),
  passport.session()
);
```

Comment: `app.use` is just a [proxy of `Router#use()`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L178).

Comment: Looking through the docs it looks like the only difference between the two would be if you wanted to specify seperate paths for your middleware functions, you would use the individual app.use calls. 
app.use('/path1', compression());

Otherwise, if they're all going to be on the same path then the app.use function allows you to define a series of middleware functions, like what you're doing on your second example.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference

Take a look at express documentation

```
app.use([path,] callback [, callback...])
```

`callback` - Callback functions can be:

- A middleware function.
- **A series of middleware functions (separated by commas).**
- An array of middleware functions.
- A combination of all of the above.

You can provide multiple callback functions that behave just like middleware, ***except that these callbacks can invoke next('route') to bypass the remaining route callback(s)***. You can use this mechanism to impose pre-conditions on a route, then pass control to subsequent routes if there is no reason to proceed with the current route.

So to be confident that your middleware executes, write them as your first version

Also notice that by default router uses `/`route, when you call `app.use` separately for each middleware, you have more control over which route they should be plugged

```
// GOOD
app.use('/', express.static(config.staticRoot, { maxAge: 300000 }));
app.use('/', compression());

// BAD
app.use('/', express.static(config.staticRoot, { maxAge: 300000 }), compression(), cookieParser());
```

Bad because `compression()` middleware could call `next('/someOtherPage');` which will skip other middlwares bound to `/`

Comment: Are you sure about that last part? I think calling `next('/someOtherPage');` will just be treated as passing an error to `next`. I believe that when the documentation says `next('route')` it literally means the string `'route'`, not a path to some other route.

Comment: I did see the bit about `next('route')` - I imagine it is not commonly used.  If we assume (or better, verify) that those middlewares never call `next('route')` is it equivalent?  What would the effect be on middlewares routes without a path (as I used in my example?)

Answer (score 0):

Invoke `app.use()` with separate statements is much more **flexible** than multiple args. Here are some examples:

1. What if some middlewares are only applied under specific condition? Like:

   ```
   if (isProductionMode) {
     app.use(middlewareOnlyInProduction);
   } else {
     app.use(middlewareOnlyInDevelopment);
   }
   ```

   Of course you can implement similar logic with `app.use.apply(...)` and pass the correct middleware array, but that would increase the complexity.
2. What if some middlewares are only applied after an async call?

   ```
   app.use(middlewareA);
   aPromise.then(function() {
     app.use(middlewareB);
   }).catch(function() {
     app.use(middlewareC);
   });
   ```

   With "multiple args" solution, there is no way to implement such logic.

With "separate statements" solution, you can add middleware no matter where or when. With "multiple args" solution, you can only add middleware once, which is very restricted.